# Can I search for a place in Here JS API without providing a location?

Tags: here-api

Reading the (not very good) documentation, it appears that location is a required parameter to search for a place in the Here JS API. Is there no way to find a place by name, without knowing the location? I want to have the map center on a user entered name of a location. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, HERE must have the location parameter for Places Search. Location biasing is not a perfect solution to map search results but it reduces the chance of getting a wrong place. Imagine looking for *Shell petrol station* without any location provided. The dirty hack here would be providing (0, 0) coordinates and some extremely big radius, which will cover the whole world. Although, this way you will get lots of wrong results for common names.

Comment: Dirty but effective hack. Closing 30 tabs after trying and confirming this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can check this within the Places API directly. There is also a bounding box possibility and some others. You will find here some more examples and the doc: https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/places

Comment: There should be a easier way to specify areas. e.g. "Search on Canada". I had to use the playground to grab the corner points. Perhaps I'm missing something